# Set a default option for a given directive in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autosummary

In Sphinx, is there a way to set a default value for a directive option in `conf.py`, so that it is always used whenever I use that directive?

In particular, I am using autosummary, and I always want `:toctree:` to be set so that I don't have to write

```
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: r
```

every time, and I never have to worry about adding the `:toctree:` part.